# How to call child method in javascript ? ( Getting error like ReferenceError: getPointInfo is not defined)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures

Can not invoke the child method from the parent method. Any help is much appreciated.

**CHILD METHOD :** getPointInfo()

**PARENT METHOD :** createPolygon()

Can not call a child method from the parent method. Actually child method is in the infoWindow object of google maps API V3.

```
function createPolygon(polygon) {
    var clat = 0;
    var clng = 0;
    var polygonShape    =[];
    var content = "<div><label><b>Name : </b></label>"
            + document.getElementById('Name').value
            + '</br><label><b>Region Name : </b></label><input type="text" size="20" id="region_name"/></br><label align="top"><b>Description : </b></label><textarea id="region_desc" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea><br/><input type="button" value="Save Region" onclick="getPointInfo();"/><br/>'
            + '<b>-----INFO-----</b>';
    var polygonPath = function() {
        var contents = content;
        var vert = polygon.getPath();
        vert.forEach(function(xy, i) {
            var contentString = '<br/><b>Lat :</b> ' + xy.lat().toFixed(6) + '<b>Long : </b>'
                + xy.lng().toFixed(6);
            contents = contents + contentString;
            clat = xy.lat();
            clng = xy.lng();
            var vertex  = {
                "lat" : xy.lat().toFixed(6),
                "lng" : xy.lng().toFixed(6)
            };
            polygonShape.push(vertex);
        });
        this.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content : contents,
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(clat,clng),
            maxWidth : 400
        });
        drawingTool.setDrawingMode(null);
        this.infoWindow.open(map);
    };
    polygonPath();

    function getPointInfo() {
        var RegionName = document.getElementById('region_name').value;
        var RegionDesc = document.getElementById('region_desc').value;
        this.infoWindow.close();
        polygonJson = {
            data : polygonShape,
            regionName : RegionName,
            regionDescription : RegionDesc 
    };
        console.log(Object.toJSON(polygonJson));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that.

Export the function first using a module pattern. It is currently private and when you reference it from DOM you need entry point.